# Can Windows DLLs be used with .NET Core 3.0 on Windows?

Tags: .net-core, .net-core-3.0

We have a WPF application that uses a 3rd party DLL to interface with another Windows application.

We are trying to migrate this application to .NET Core 3.0 but having an issue using the DLL.

Can Windows DLLs for .NET Framework be used with .NET Core 3.0 on Windows?

Comment: Yes they can. .net core can also use com as well

Comment: Most of them can be reused if you just want to recompile and run. However, due to the new WPF designer, the designer support might be broken. Vendors of such controls should ship .NET Core WPF specific updates right now.

Comment: @LexLi WPF portion worked fine for us.  It's a non-WPF DLL we're having trouble with.

Comment: Non-WPF assemblies follow a similar rule. Most of them should automatically work for .NET Core apps on Windows, but some can break as no doubt they were not designed for it. You have to edit your question to be more specific on one or a few assemblies. Too general a question cannot be answered.

Comment: @LexLi It was answered and put us in the right direction.  Thanks.